# How do I only browse the northern, southern, eastern and western part of any square matrix (without going through the whole matrix)?

Tags: c++, matrix

What limits should i and j have inside the for in order to only go through the highlided areas in [image: This picture] (Without the diagonals)
 ?

A pair of two fors for each of the four areas:

```
 for(i=?;i<?;i?)
    for(j=?;j<?;j?)
       cout<<matrix[i][j];
```

Comment: what did you try? You have an example with all the indices, start by writing a loop for that (4x4) then try to generalize

Comment: btw why without going through the whole matrix? excluding the diagonals is much easier than getting the four other parts seperately

Comment: Actually, your example is a bit small to be exact. Do you want to get the whole matrix without the diagonals or just the one row/column at each of the sides of the matrix (its the same in the picture). From your post I think its the first, but I am a bit unsure. Furhtermore, do you have a requirement on the order in which you pass the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code generates the correct output for the northern part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Index
{
    int i;
    int j;
    void out(){std::cout << i << "," << j << "  ";}
};

int size = 8;

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<Index>> Matrix(size);

  for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<size; ++j)
    {
       Index Idx;
       Idx.i = i;
       Idx.j = j;
       Matrix[i].push_back(Idx);
       Idx.out();
    }
    std::cout <<std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "--------------------------" <<std::endl;

  int half_size = size/2;

  for(int i=0; i<half_size; ++i)
  {
    for(int j=i+1; j<size-i-1; ++j)
    {
        Matrix[i][j].out();
    }
  }
}
```

[Run the above code online](http://www.cpp.sh/23nlg).
For `int size = 8` the output reads:

```
0,0  0,1  0,2  0,3  0,4  0,5  0,6  0,7  
1,0  1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4  1,5  1,6  1,7  
2,0  2,1  2,2  2,3  2,4  2,5  2,6  2,7  
3,0  3,1  3,2  3,3  3,4  3,5  3,6  3,7  
4,0  4,1  4,2  4,3  4,4  4,5  4,6  4,7  
5,0  5,1  5,2  5,3  5,4  5,5  5,6  5,7  
6,0  6,1  6,2  6,3  6,4  6,5  6,6  6,7  
7,0  7,1  7,2  7,3  7,4  7,5  7,6  7,7  
--------------------------
0,1  0,2  0,3  0,4  0,5  0,6  1,2  1,3  1,4  1,5  2,3  2,4
```

For the southern, eastern and western part please modify my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think "without going through the whole matrix" is a weird requirement. In one way or the other you have to go trough the whole matrix. Only certain elements are to be skipped. So for the sake of this answer I'll simply ignore that requirement ;).

You didn't specify what type is the matrix, so I'll assume its an array of arrays.

```
std::array< std::array<double,N> , N> matrix;    

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        if ( i == j) continue; // skip diagonal
        if ( i + j == N) continue; // skip anti-diagonal
        std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << matrix[i][j] << '\n';
    }
}
```

**PS** I missed the "for each of the four areas". Anyhow, all we need to add is a way to decide in which quarter of the matrix an element belongs to:

```
enum Location { NORTH,SOUTH,EAST,WEST,DIAG,UNDEFINED };
enum RelativeLocation { Above, Below };

Location localize(int i,int j,int n){
    if ( i == j || i+j == n-1) return DIAG;
    auto diag = ( i > j ) ? Above : Below;
    auto anti = ( i+j < n) ? Above : Below;
    if (diag == Above) return (anti == Above) ? WEST : NORTH;
    if (diag == Below) return (anti == Above) ? SOUTH : EAST;
    return UNDEFINED;
}
```

You did not specifiy what exactly you want to do with the elements in the loop, so I dare to claim that you can always refactor four loops into one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        auto l = localize(i,j);
        if (l == NORTH) do_something_with_north_elements(i,j,matrix[i][j]);
        else if (l == EAST) do_something_with_east_elements(i,j,matrix[i][j]);
        // ... 
    }
```

}

To see it in action, here is a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::map<Location,std::function<void()>> do_something {
        { NORTH,    [](){std::cout << 'n';} },
        { EAST,     [](){std::cout << 'e';} },
        { SOUTH,    [](){std::cout << 's';} },
        { WEST,     [](){std::cout << 'w';} },
        { DIAG,     [](){std::cout << 'd';} },
        { UNDEFINED,[](){std::cout << 'x';} }
    };
    const int N = 4;
    for (int i=0;i<N;++i) {
        for (int j=0;j<N;++j) {
            do_something[ localize(i,j,N) ]();
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }       
}
```

it prints

```
dssd
wdde
wdde
dnnd
```

[Live@Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Pb2JVEIw2CiVCK7X)

Comment: "without going through the whole matrix" is indeed a weird requirement. But it is the requirement!